# What is the distribution of $Z = X - 1$ given the distribution of $X$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Here is the problem found in the book "Probability and Statistics - The Science of Uncertainty" (problem 2.3.23) :

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability function $p_X (x) = 2^{−x}$ for
$x = 1,2,3,...$ , with $p_X (x) = 0$ otherwise.
Let $Z = X − 1$. What is the distribution of $Z$? (Identify the distribution by name
and specify all parameter values.)

Here is what I did so far :

$P_Z(z)=P_{x-1}(z)=2^{1-z}$ for $x = 0, 1, 2,...$ with $P_Z(z)=0$ elsewhere else.
I am struggling when it comes to find the name of the distribution. $Z$ is looking like a binomial distribution :

$2^{1-z} = 2(\frac{1}{2})^z = 2(\frac{1}{2})^\frac{z}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})^{z-\frac{z}{2}}$ but the problem is that $\binom{z}{\frac{z}{2}} \neq 2$ (given that $z$ is only an even number).

Or

$2^{1-z} = 2(\frac{1}{2})^z = 4(\frac{1}{2})^{z}(1-\frac{1}{2})^{z-z}$ but here we don't have that $\binom{z}{z} = 4$ either.

Can you see where I did a mistake ?

Comment: Note that $X$ takes infinitely many values $1,2,3,...$ so $Z$ takes infinitely many values $0,1,2,...$. The binomial distribution does not take infinitely many values, so $Z$ cannot be binomial.

Comment: @snar Good thinking !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting distribution is the following

$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{2^x}$$

$x=1,2,3,...$

It is a geometric distribution

$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=q^{x-1}p$$

with $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$

the resulting distribution

$$\mathbb{P}(X-1=z)=\mathbb{P}(X=z+1)=\frac{1}{2^{z+1}}$$

$z=0,1,2,...$

is always a geometric distribution with parameter $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$

$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=q^{x}p$$

the only difference is that the first distribution counts the numbers of trials before the first success while the second one counts the failures.

Some textbooks call the first distribution "Modified Geometric" but in general there is no a common name to distinguish the two laws

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) you can find the two laws duly described.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I can see that in those cases, one should start by writing $P(Z=z) = P(X-1=z) = P(X=z+1) = 2^{1+z}$ and not (as I wrote) $P(Z=z) = P(X-1=z) = 2^{1-z} $. How do you know which one to use ? I can see me make the same mistake in a few weeks

Comment: @AlanSimonin : to use the former or the latter depends on the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a geometric distribution with parameter $p = \frac12$. That is, it describes the number of trials before, but not including, the first success in a sequence of i.i.d. trials with probability $p$ of success.

Whether the successful trial is included in the tally is a matter of convention - those who refer to $Z$ as a geometric distribution might call $X$ a first success distribution, while others would call $X$ geometric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !